# Syntax of Vue.js filter within v-bind:href

Tags: vue.js

I am declaring a html hyperlink with vue.js. The URL is set up by concatenating lets say "baseurl" and "id". However, I need to format the "id" first. I am trying to use a vue.js filter to process the "id" before concatenating with "baseurl". However, the filter applies to the whole URL, and not just to "id", which is what I want.

Let's say:

`longid = "myprefix.id"`

I want to obtain:

`<a href="https://mysite.mydatabase?ID=id">longid</a>`

I got this if I do:

`<a v-bind:href="'https://mysite.mydatabase?ID='+longid.substring(longid.indexOf('.')+1)">{{ longid }}</a>`

However, I wanted to do it with a vue.js filter, which I like more. I tried:

`<a v-bind:href="'https://mysite.mydatabase?ID='+longid | shorten">{{ longid }}</a>`

With the filter declared as:

```
filters: {
        shorten: function(myString){
            return myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)
        }
    },
```

This is applied to the whole URL, and not just to "longid", so I finally have:

`href="id"`

instead of

`href="https://mysite.mydatabase?ID=id"`

I also tried to enclose the substring and the filter within parentheses:

`<a v-bind:href="'https://mysite.mydatabase?ID='+ ( longid | shorten )">{{ longid }}</a>`

but then I got a `ReferenceError` claming that the filter is not defined.

How can I make the filter apply only to "longid", being afterwards concatenated with the rest of the URL?

Comment: Have you tried template literals ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I get here is that you are trying to use a filter as method. You can achieve this using this.$options.filters.filterName().
For the given case, you should try something like:

`<a v-bind:href="'https://mysite.mydatabase?ID='+$options.filters.shorten(longid )">{{ longid }}</a>`.

Fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/sharitu/nbm2v1dx/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define method shorten and use like

`` <a v-bind:href="`https://mysite.mydatabase?ID=${shorten(longid)}`">{{ longid }}</a> ``

2. Consider change your `shorten` function:

```
shorten: function(myString){
   return myString.split('.').pop()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
     <a v-bind:href="'https://mysite.mydatabase?ID='+longid | shorten(longid)">{{ longid }}</a>
```

Your filters function should change like this:

```
     filters: {
         shorten: function(myString,longid){
            //return your code;
         }
     },
```

First argument is the url and second argument is longid parameter

Comment: Will report shorten undefined. @Ritu's answer is right